# Firebase Hosting copy and paste dynamic url not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, url-routing, firebase-hosting, url-parameters

I'm stuck on where to search / what to search for regarding this issue, so I'm looking for some help.

I have a site that has user-generated posts with uid's. When someone navigates through the site, everything works totally fine, but when the url is copied and pasted into a new tab, I get a blank screen and a tab that won't load.

My routes go from "/" to

```
<Route path="/listings" element={<ListingsPage />} />
```

then to

```
<Route path="/listings/:id" element={<ListingDetailPage />} />
```

once the post is clicked on.

I'm not sure if this is a routing issue, or a dynamic link issue, or some type of issue that can be fixed with SSR / cloud functions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know Firebase's open source cloud function github example is about 4 years old now, wondering if that's still applicable.